# Automatic syntax highlighter

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a good all rounded syntax highlighter written in JavaScript that will auto detect the language used and apply proper syntax highlighting.

I've found a myriad of them from a simple Google search but they all have to have some sort of formatted class on the `<pre>` element like `<pre class="highlight-php">`.

I noticed StackOverflow's syntax highlighting manages to do it automatically from within pre blocks, anyone know what library they're using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

They are using [google prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).  There are other options, such as [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)

Comment: highlight.js seems by far the best solution.